# Make a correct POST request and get response data

Tags: javascript, post, request, fetch

I have an application hosted on `pythonanywhere.com`. It throws a 400 error if sended data does not contain `data` property, otherwise it returns a response data. This is Flask code of the server:

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def get_post():
    if not request.json or not 'data' in request.json:
        abort(400)
    data = request.json['data']
    # do something with the data...
    return jsonify({'response': str(data)}), 200
```

And my front-end part of application should send a POST request with a data and get a response. I am trying to use `fetch` but it gets a 400 error though I send a JSON object with a `data` object:

```
function sendData(value) {
  data = { 'data': value };
  fetch('http://' + appUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      mode: 'no-cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
  .then(data => { return data.json() })
}
```

Also I tried to use `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'http://' + appUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(data);
```

But I can't find out how to disable CORS and get a response data.

Comment: if it's CORS issue, better check your server, assuming you are trying to do an http request from a different source (other than `pythonanywhere.com`), found this 
https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. hope this can help

Comment: @noobHere, thank you very much, your solution worked for me. I used fetch without no-cors mode and successfuly got a response. You can make an answer and I will check it as a solution.

Comment: glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are having CORS issue, always check if the server accept your origin of request (other than `pythonanywhere.com`) if not, you should allow it from your server.

you mentioned that you are using Flask as your backend, you might want to check out this library:

https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

if you follow the docs from the link, you can allow, accept http request depends on the parameter you provided.

Happy Coding